# Does it make sense to mine Monero if I have free electricity?

Tags: mining

I have the opportunity to use "free" electricity for keeping one computer running all day and night. 
To be clear, the electricity is not actually free of course, it's that I won't be paying the bill.

I wonder if it makes sense to build a computer and use it for mining Monero since there will be no electricity costs, but even if I do, how much could I make out of it? Does it make sense if I am anyway investing some money in buying a good computer for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How much you might generate in XMR will very much depend on how powerful the computer is you plan on buying. For example, a RaspberryPi probably wont earn you much at all, but a multi-socket EPYC server is another thing entirely. Of course, how much electricity these use is also very different, therefore you should probably double check with the electricity bill payer before investing in a machine that is going to consume more electricity than a typical home PC does.